Laravel, $query, Trouble with Laravel Eloquent orderBy when sorting by related table column
I'm encountering an issue with Laravel Eloquent while trying to order query results by a column from a related table. Specifically, I have a recipes table and a related nutrients table, and I want to order recipes by the kcal column in the nutrients table.
Here's the code snippet I'm using:
$query = Recipe::with('nutrients');

// more code


if ($request->has('order_by')) {
        $orderBy = $request->input('order_by');
        $direction = $request->input('order_direction', 'asc');

        // some code
            
        elseif ($orderBy === 'kcal') {
            if ($request->has('kcal')) {
                $kcal = $request->input('kcal');
                $query->whereHas('nutrients', function ($q) use ($kcal) {
                    $q->where('kcal', '<=', $kcal);
                });
            }
            $query->orderBy('nutrients.kcal', $direction);
        }
}

// some code
return RecipesResource::collection($recipes);

Models:
Recipe:
public function nutrients()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Nutrient::class, 'recipe_id', 'id');
    }

Nutrient:
public function recipe()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Recipe::class);
    }

However, this code is resulting in an SQL error: "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'nutrients.kcal' in 'order clause'". It seems like Laravel is not recognizing the kcal column in the nutrients table when trying to order the results.
I've tried different approaches, including explicitly specifying the table name in the orderBy clause, but so far, I haven't been able to resolve the issue.
Can anyone provide insight into why this error is occurring and how to properly order query results by a column from a related table in Laravel Eloquent?

instead of using $query->orderBy('nutrients.kcal', $direction); ....
Please use $query->join('nutrients', 'recipes.id', '=', 'nutrients.recipe_id') /* Join the nutrients table */               ->orderBy('nutrients.kcal', $direction);  /* Order by nutrients.kcal*/
We should use join to explicitly join the nutrients table on the recipes table using the foreign key relationship.

with() and whereHas() don't perform any kind of join on your SQL, so nutrients.kcal is not going to work. You need to explicitly join your tables, like ->join('nutrients', ...) (replacing ... with the columns/operator your want to join on), then you can use orderBy('nutrients.kcal').

The reason this error is thrown is because laravel divides your query into multiple queries. It first queries your recipes table. After which it extracts the ids from that result and runs a wherein query on your nutrients table. This means that during your first query the nutrients table is not loaded, hence the error is being thrown that it cannot find the column.
You can prevent this by using a join statement instead.
$query->join('nutrients', 'id', '=', 'nutrients.id')
    ->whereHas('nutrients', function($q) use ($kcal) {
        return $q->where('kcal', '<=', $kcal);
    })
    ->orderBy('nutrients.kcal', $direction);


No matter what is your code quality , After reviewing your code , I think the issue lies here :
 $query->whereHas('nutrients', function ($q) use ($kcal) {
                $q->where('kcal', '<=', $kcal);
            });

Change this "$q->where('kcal', '<=', $kcal);" to "$q->where('nutrients.kcal', '<=', $kcal);" , I assumed that "nutrients" table does have 'kcal' column exists , Thanks if it helps.

Incorrect. $q is a subquery that is localized to the nutrients table, so where('kcal', ...) and where('nutrients.kcal', ...) would be equivalent.
